# Javascript average of first column from 2 row

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, average

```html
<table>
 <tr>
  <th>Numbers</th>
  <th>Names</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <th>2</th>
  <th>Name 1</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <th>26</th>
  <th>Name 2</th>
 </tr>
</table>
```

In my code the rows are imported from a database so they will all be from row 2 in the table.

I want to find the average number of all the numbers in the first column from the second row as the first row just has text in it.

Comment: Provide please some code that you've tried to do it and what are the issues

Comment: I dont know how I would do this. Im asking if anyone knows a code that would work to get the average of first column from 2 row. And then console.log the answer.

Comment: If this is rendered on the server, just calculate the AVG() in the SQL query already and include it somewhere in the page. If it's client-side rendered, try getting the raw data in an array so you don't have to look at the rendered table and can just loop the raw array. Worst case, just select the first cell of second row and on and parseInt the text inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Object#values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values), [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), and [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

```js
const dataElements = document.querySelectorAll("table tr:not(:first-child) > th:first-child");

const res = Object.values(dataElements)
.reduce((a,c)=>a+Number(c.innerText),0)/dataElements.length;

console.log(res);
```

```html
<table> <tr> <th>Numbers</th> <th>Names</th> </tr><tr> <th>2</th> <th>Name 1</th> </tr><tr> <th>26</th> <th>Name 2</th> </tr></table>
```

Comment: Thank you, works fine and is easy to understand! Nice work